# Auto-dial a code after a telephone number on mobile websites

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

On our website, you can make micropayments by dialing a certain telephone number and entering a 6-digit code. Would it be possible to auto-dial this number, or appending it behind the telephone number, so this 6-digit code will be entered automatically?

If it works on either android or iPhone it'd already help a lot, though a cross-solution would obviously be preferrable.

Comment: I noticed this behavior is different on iPhone where it automatically dials but on Android it auto populates the dialer but the user has to press the green phone icon for it to make the call automatically.  I would like android to do the same as the iPhone but I don't think there is a way.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go

Add following permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE">
```

Then call this method

```
private void call() {
    try {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234")); //you put desired phone number
        startActivity(callIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("helloandroid dialing example", "Call failed", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i think i wasn't clear enough: It's on a website ;) For iPhone, using a semicolon or comma works, though apparently it does not on android.